# Google sheets vertical multi line Chart

Tags: google-sheets, graph, google-visualization, spreadsheet, measure

I want to make a vertical google chart with multiple lines.

So for whatever reason I thought it would be interesting to see and track the progress of my finger mobility after my recent surgery with a google sheets spreadsheet and chart.  Every so often at Physical Therapy they measure the angle of my finger.  I haven't received the measurements yet so I have only been working with random numbers for the meantime.

[image: Graph Line Comparison]

So This is kind of what I was thinking either with the different days separated or overlaid on top of each.
Is this possible and if so how could I do this?
As a bonus it would be cool to have the angles at the joints of the graph but I'm not sure if that's possible either.

Thanks for indulging my curiosity.

- EDIT *

I was working on a version that almost got what I was wanting I just could not figure out how to add multiple to the same chart or to overlay them

[image]

This was with the help of [Vertical Line Graph in Google Sheets (Workaround)](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/vertical-line-graph-in-google-sheets/) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can achieve it:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that's not quite what I am looking for I have tried making a few graphs/charts in google sheets and most of them are like what you show above.
I want the line to also have the same shape as my finger from the measured angles.
I'll add a photo of the closest I was able to get to the main post.

Comment: @aladams I'm not rly an expert on behavioral finger fracture mechanics but most fingers I've seen have 3 joints so you will need only 4 rows where the "healed" finger when viewed from the side is strait line at 45° angle like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGt3i.png (and that's how the proposed solution would be implemented - or as I imagined it)